# How to get time in mm:ss format in App Inventor

Tags: app-inventor

I am making an app for myself in app inventor which calculates time. There are two buttons (start, stop) and a label to display the time.

Now my problem is that I get the resultant time which is (stop time - start time) in milliseconds but I want it in `MM:SS` format. I tried certain clock buttons like get instant from milliseconds and time format too, but still failed to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

see the screenshot how to do it
[image]
for a complete example of a countdown timer see [here](http://puravidaapps.com/countdown.php)

Comment: Thankyou got it. can u please help me for one more question, i have calculated time and stored in tinydb and it is stored in this way (00:01 00:02 00:03 ..... ) and when i upload it to server it is uploaded in the same manner there which is trouble making because on server it appears like this in time column(00:01 00:02 ...) .which is wrong , it must be in vertical manner . can you please help me how to store data in tinydb in app inventor column wise. i have also put \n in code but still data stores in single line.

Comment: In case your question is answered, please mark it as answered, see also [here how stackoverflow works](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). And for new questions, ask a new one instead of continuing here. Thank you.